# Examples in $W^{1,p}(U)\setminus C(\overline{U})$ and $C(\overline{U})\setminus W^{1,p}(U)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The following is the trace theorem in *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans:

> Let $U$ be a domain (open connected subset) of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Then there exists a bounded linear operator
>   $$
> T:W^{1,p}(U)\to L^p(\partial U)
> $$
>   such that
>     $Tu=u\mid_{\partial U}$ if $u\in W^{1,p}(U)\cap C(\overline{U})$
>   and 
>   $$
> \|Tu\|_{L^p(\partial U)}\leq C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}
> $$
>   for each $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$, with $C=C(p,U)$.

I don't know how different $W^{1,p}(U)$ and $C(\overline{U})$ can be. Would anybody help me with simple examples in $W^{1,p}(U)\setminus C(\overline{U})$ and $C(\overline{U})\setminus W^{1,p}(U)$?

Comment: given the dimension of $U$ and w.l.o.g. $0\in U$ you can for instance check for which $m$ the map $x\mapsto \left|x\right|^{-m}$ (which is clearly discontinous) is part of $W^{1,p}$ (that means integrable including derivatives)

For the other case, you might check rapidly fast oscillating functions - but that is just an idea. (something around $x\mapsto \sin(\left|x\right|^{-1})$)

Comment: couldnt edit anymore, sry for double post: another example for the first case: take only the first $k$ components of $x$ and replace $\left|x\right|^{-m}$ with $\left|\left(x_1,...,x_k\right)\right|^{-m}$ - which would be a discontinuity at a $n-k$-dimensional hypersurface (if $\dim(U)=n$)

Answer (score 2):

Continuous but not in any Sobolev space: let $f(x)=g(x_1)$ where $g$ is a continuous but not absolutely continuous: Cantor staircase, or a Weierstrass-type nowhere differentiable function. Since Sobolev functions are absolutely continuous on almost every line segment parallel to a coordinate axis, $f$ is not in $W^{1,p}$.

In $W^{1,p}(U)$ but without a continuous extension to $\overline{U}$: this requires $p\le n$, because for $p>n$ the Morrey-Sobolev inequality gives Hölder continuity, and that propagates to the boundary. Pick a point $x_0\in \partial U$ and let $u(x)=\log \log \frac{1}{\|x-x_0\|}$. This function is in $W^{1,p}(U)$ for $1\le p\le n$ (provided $n\ge 2$), but has no continuous extension to the boundary.